# Error Trying to run Procedure from Another Form

Tags: ms-access, vba, procedure, calling-convention

I'm trying to call a Sub from another Form, but I get:

> `Error 2465: Application defined error or object defined error`

I already know that to call a procedure from another form I can use the syntax:

```
 Form(Name).Procedure
```

But, in this case I want to refer to this form from a variable (Type Form).

**Code from form `Parametro_Cadastro`:**

```
Dim formCaller As Form
Set formCaller = Application.Forms("Cadastro_Aluno").Form
If (Not formCaller Is Nothing) Then
    '
    formCaller.SetDadosParametroCadastro Me.txtKey.Value, dadoAlterado
    Set formCaller = Nothing
End If
```

**Code from form `Cadastro_Aluno`**:

```
Sub SetDadosParametroCadastro(ByVal KeyValue As String, ByVal DataValue As String)
    '
    '...
End Sub
```

The code in `Parametro_Cadastro` gives `Error 2465` on the line:

```
formCaller.SetDadosParametroCadastro Me.txtKey.Value, dadoAlterado`
```

...even before the Sub `SetDadosParametroCadastro`in the form `Cadastro_Alunos` to be called.

In the Immediate Window, the variable `formCaller` is already signed as `Form\Form_Cadastro_Alunos` as expected.

What can I do in this case?

**EDIT**

The only way it worked was to assign the variable `formCaller` to `Access.Forms(formName)` and not through `Application.Forms(formName)` or simply `Forms(formName)`, so the code now is like below:

**Code from form `Parametro_Cadastro`:**

```
Dim formCaller As Form
Set formCaller = Access.Forms("Cadastro_Aluno")
If (Not formCaller Is Nothing) Then
    '
    formCaller.SetDadosParametroCadastro Me.txtKey.Value, dadoAlterado
    Set formCaller = Nothing
End If
```

When I check the variable `formCaller` in the Imediate Window, I also get (as before) `Forms\Form_Cadastro_Alunos`.
The interesting thing is this only change make the code work as expected. Maybe the Forms member to be called is from Access Object instead of Applications?

Comment: What does the error ***say***?  (I don't memorize error code numbers.)

Comment: @ashleedawg Error 2465 stands for "Application defined error or object defined error" (maybe it's not accurate the description, because I receive the error description in Portuguese)

Comment: That sounds like the correct translation, thanks.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Although you ***can*** call a procedure from a form, it's generally *avoided* and is considered bad practice.

Any `Sub` or `Function` that need to be shared should be placed in a **separate, shared module**.

---

*Some excellent advice from [Stewart](https://bytes.com/profile/171872/stewart-ross/) @ [Bytes.com](https://bytes.com/profile/171872/stewart-ross/):*

> Form code modules are essentially 'private' in scope. Functions and subroutines defined in them are normally **unavailable** outside of the form concerned - although it is actually possible to call the functions and subroutines defined as `Public` in scope within a form code module from outside of that module.
>
> Use of the keyword `Public` is not just a matter of suddenly adding one as a change of style. It reflects that you wish the subroutine, function or variable to be available outside of the scope of the code module concerned...
>
> The code modules which can be created or opened from the <kbd>Modules</kbd> tab are the *usual* locations of public subroutines and functions. **Named modules provide a means of grouping tasks by logical function, and if used consistently can be an aid to maintainability.**
>
> I use many *several* named modules in my applications, separating custom linked table maintenance from username parsing, e-mail handling and so on. I also include a *"General"* module which contains general bespoke functions that I find useful and re-use across multiple databases (for example, to return the current financial year or the current quarter within it).
>
> All subroutines and functions defined using the `Public` keyword in the publicly-accessible code modules are available outside of the module concerned, whereas those defined as Private cannot be used outside of the scope of the code module in which they reside.

---

### <sub>*"If you must..."*</sub>

If, for some reason, you *must* call a public sub from a form, the syntax is:

```
Call Forms!FormName.SubName
```

- Note that the sub being called must have the `Public` keyword specified.

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [Understanding Scope and Visibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/understanding-scope-and-visibility)
- Bytes.com : [How and where to use Private or Public sub or function?](https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/906946-how-where-use-private-public-sub-function#post3643855)

Comment: Great explanation, in fact I use to have modules for the codes I have to share across the Project. In this case, the procedure is inside the Form code because I need access to some controls of that form.

Comment: Yeah there are lots reasons to keep code properly organized. I keep a folder on my desktop with saved `.BAS` (text) copies of various modules I might use again *(ie. "the  email one", "the disk access one", "the scraping one", etc)*, for easy import into future projects, and also a handy "known working" copy to reference when troubleshooting a currently-used "version".

Comment: I tried to use `Call Forms!FormName.SubName` and didn't work. But assigning the `formCaller variable as formCaller = Access.Forms(formName)` and then `formCaller.Procedure` now worked fine. I dont know why...